# How to enable deep-linking in WebView on Android app?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to implement deep linking in android app.

When I click the deep linking of custom url (xxxx://repost?id=12) on Android browser like Chrome, my app opens up and works very well.

Problem is, in the app, there's a webView widget, and I want to the deep-linking work there too.

Currently, it's showing `Can't connect to the server` error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Override shouldOverrideUrlLoading function handle by yourself if url.startsWith(APP_SCHEME)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is the problem with android web view as this treats everything as URL but other browser like chrome on mobile intercepts the scheme and OS will do the rest to open the corresponding app. 
To implement this you need to modify your web view shouldOverrideUrlLoading functions as follows:

```
 @Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        LogUtils.info(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading: " + url);
        Intent intent;

        if (url.contains(AppConstants.DEEP_LINK_PREFIX)) {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);

            return true;
        } 
 }
```

In above code replace AppConstants.DEEP_LINK_PREFIX with your url scheme eg.

> android-app://your package

Hope this helps!!

Comment: This is bound to fail if the user does not have the other app installed

Comment: This is about opening the deep link for your app from your app web view. please see the question? If there is something i am missing please elaborate.

Comment: if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) 
This will check if intent can be started

Comment: if you are deeplinking to the same app, this will open the app again but branch InitSessionComplete() won't be triggered unfortunately. Anyone knows a fix ?

Comment: @Pranav what happens if we dont know the deeplink prefix ?

Answer (score 12):

The answer of @pranav is perfect but might cause crash if there are no apps to handle the intent. @georgianbenetatos's solution to prevent that helps

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
   startActivity(intent);
} else {
   Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_apps_to_handle_intent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: This will always chrome / browser right ?

Comment: @droidev whoever access ACTION_VIEW, like browsers and other apps.

Comment: most of the devices will have web browsers right ? and which will be always accepts `ACTION_VIEW` and in this case browser will be always opened right ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct @droidev

Comment: Is there any better way ? just like chrome handles ? in chrome if you try to open any deeplink url it will directly open/asks to open the deeplinkable application right ?

Comment: If you enable deeplink on your app, it work properly for your app as well.