# How to get deep link working in WebView

Tags: android, webview, deep-linking

I had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672330/how-to-enable-deep-linking-in-webview-on-android-app) but it seems that the things changed in API 23 as the scheme is no more `android-app://`.

My deep link works well in Chrome but not in WebView.

Currently my link is the following one:

```
<a href='intent://www.example.com/webservice?site=whynot&theme=xx&lang=fr#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.ndguide.ndguide;end'>My Intent Link</a>
```

And so I intercept the url like below:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Intent intent;

    if (url.contains("intent://")) {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    }
    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `not work in WebView`? Ensure `url.contains("intent://")` capture your IntentLink then you only need to start it. Btw, I think you will get an `ActivityNotFoundException` if there is no app response your `IntentLink`.

Comment: @saki_M, yes this what I finally done, I simply process the url internally. thanks

Comment: So is there any other problem?

Comment: @saki_M No more in my specific case. Thanks.